# How does this quotient by a maximal ideal looks like?

Tags: abstract-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals, quotient-spaces, principal-ideal-domains

I have the following situation:

> Let $R$ be a PID. Then let $\mathfrak{p}\subset R$ be a maximal ideal. We consider the set $$\left(R/\mathfrak{p}\right)[X]$$ which is clearly a quotient, but I would like to know how does equivalence classes (cosets) looks like in this set because I can't imagine this.

It would also be nice if you could give a small explanation why it looks exaclty in this way.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Try $R=\mathbb Z$...

Comment: So I mean if I take $R=\Bbb{Z}$ then as I remember every Ideal is of the form $n\Bbb{Z}$ for some $n\geq 1$ right? i.e. every ideal can be written as $(n)$?

Comment: Yes, and for which $n$ is $n\Bbb{Z}$ maximal?

Comment: I would say for all prime numbers? because only then $\mathbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}$ is a field. is this correct?

Comment: Yes. Now describe $(\mathbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z})[X]$.

Comment: But then if this is correct for example I can take $n=2$ and get that $$\mathfrak{p}:=2\Bbb{Z}=\{0,\pm 2,\pm 4,\pm 6,\pm 8,... \}$$ which is a maximal Ideal. Then $R/\mathfrak{p}=\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}=\{[0],[1]\}$ and then $\left(R/\mathfrak{p}\right)[X]$ are polynomials with coefficiant $[0]$ or $[1]$? or are the coefficiants elements in the equivalence classes